# Replace windows carriage returns in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, parsing

I have a text file that I'm trying to parse into an array in Javascript.

The fields are delimited by a double carat ('^^') and lines are terminated by a newline ('\n')

One of the fields is a free flowing text description and the users often enter data by copying and pasting it from a PDF. This introduces rouge carriage returns into my stream ('\r\n').

The stream looks like this:

```
Silver^^NM-GNF-000230^^Y^^18-JUN-13^^1800^^07-JUN-13^^L^^WF^^Matt Reidy^^2^^NM^^GNF^^Grant^^32.888889^^107.809722^^Vicinity of Kingston, NM^^24800^^ACRES^^5^^^^Highly varied fuels ranging from dry mixed conifer at the highest elevations to ponderosa pine, Pinyon-Juniper and interior chaparral dominate the lower elevations. Fuel loading is high due to lack of fire disturbance in past century.^^Extreme^^5590600 Ward Gulch^^CO-GWD-122^^Y^^18-JUN-13^^1730^^14-JUN-13^^L^^WF^^Jeff Berino^^3^^CO^^GWD^^Garfield^^39.689167^^107.734722^^10 miles North of Rifle, Colorado^^485^^ACRES^^95^^19-JUN-13^^Pinon juniper, sage, mixed conifer^^High^^1500000
```

There is a linefeed between 5590600 and Ward Gulch which determines the start of a new record.

I have searched for a regex to replace the CR/LFs in my text and here's what I have:

```
var eplaceCarriageReturns = function(str) {
  var regxp = /[\r\n]/g
  str = str.replace(regxp, " ");
  return str;
}
```

The problem is, this now eats my linefeeds too, turning my stream into one big block. If that's the only way, I'm drawing a blank on how to parse it as my newlines were the only thing to signify a new record.

This problem has plagued me for years. I've solved it in Ruby by just removing all "CR/LF"s and then converting replacing remaining newlines with '^^'. This allows me to string.split('^^') and then chunk every 23 slices into a new array.

Can't seem to figure it out in Javascript though.

Comment: So just replace the CR using `/\r/g`? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Well, `/[\r\n]/g` is a character class, so it will match any occurrences of *either* `\r` or `\n`, but not the two of them combined. Perhaps you only want to match when they are next to each other? That would be `/\r\n/g`.

Comment: I think you're onto something with that. I think my regex isn't doing what I thought it was. I'm gonna check it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var regxp = /\r\n/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just be doing this replacement:

```
str = str.replace(/\r/g, "");
```